What does "иного толка" mean? Is it an obsolete meaning?
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ published by Iosif Bikerman (a Jewish general in the White Army) in 1924:

Кадетъ или лѣвый иного толка можетъ, запершись самъ другъ съ женой,
говорить: «жиды погубили Россію»

Левый иного толка - толк usually means "sense". Where it means "doctrine, trend, sort", it is meant to be obsolete. I could understand this if it meant "leftist of another ideological persuasion", but then that uses an obsolete meaning. Have I got it right?

There are two possible readings of this phrase.
First, it can mean what it says on the tin: "a K-D (Constitutional Democrat) or a left-winger of another persuasion (not K-D)".
Secondly, иной might mean "some", or, better yet, "there exist some such that". This meaning is mentioned on Wiktionary (sense 2).


Иные лекарства опасней самих болезней
There are cures that are worse than diseases.

Иной читатель скажет, что с такими характеристиками ракетчикам вообще, мол, не стоило волноваться. // [Олег Фаличев. Месть «Фаворита». В ответ на удар «противника» из космоса // «Воздушно-космическая оборона», 2002]
Some readers would say that with specs like that, the rocket designers should not have had anything to worry about at all.



If that's the case, the reading would be: "a K-D, or maybe a left-winger of a certain kind that exist out there, would …".
I'm inclined to believe that the former reading is the intended one, but can't completely rule out the latter one either.

As for the word толк itself, the set phrase какого-либо толка (gen. sg.) does mean "of a certain persuasion" or "of a certain variety". In the former sense, it's in no way obsolete and is widely used to describe political, ideological, and religious persuations or adherence. In the latter sense, it is a little bit dated, but still is widely used (usually, with a zest of irony):


Исключение составляют лишь издания национал-патриотического толка. // [Никита Войткевич. Критика // «Октябрь», 2013]
Как правило, они именуют себя реформатами, но есть и евангельские течения кальвинистского толка — пресвитериане, евангелисты. // [Роман Лункин. Христианский ответ обществу потребления // «Эксперт», 2013]
Их интересуют прежде всего заведения сексуального толка: гоу-гоу бары, салоны эротического массажа, «пусси-шоу» и пивные бары с девушками, понапичканные по всем местам возможной дислокации клиентов. // [А. С. Шигапов. Бангкок и Паттайя. Путеводитель (2013)]


